# what is a more efficient way to implement enqueue in Java

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, queue

So I have this simple code in java. It enqueue (adds) and element to the end of the queue (implemented by an ArrayList) without changing the original queue. The code:

```
public class MyQueue<T>{
private List<T> body;

// some constructors and helper functions.

//copy constructor
public Queue(List<T> list){
this.body = list;
}

//this is the function
public MyQueue<T> enqueue(T obj){
List<T> temp = new ArrayList<T>(body);
temp.add(obj);
return new Queue<T>(temp);
}
```

The whole Idea is to make enqueue faster and more efficient, and again, as you notice, without changing the value of the original queue.

UPDATE For the sake of completing the idea.

1- This is an assignment so university, the skeleton provided is not to be changed, the task is to make the function enqueue faster (i do realize i am copying twice and thats the slow part).

2- As for the helper functions, they are simple:

```
public T peek(){
if(body.isEmpty()){
   thrown new NoSuchElementException();
}
return body.get(0);
}

public int size(){
return body.size();
}
```

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Is it not efficient enough? How have you profiled the application?

Comment: depends what do you want to do with the items?

Comment: Have you tried java's own [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) ? Why do you think that it is not enough efficient ?

Comment: I am provided with a skeleton that states it needs to be faster.

Comment: You're saying "i am copying twice" but I can't see it. There's copying in the `ArrayList` ctor and that's all. There might be copying when the new element gets added, so the capacity accepting ctor might be better.

Answer (score 1):

A queue is a basic data structure and it's hard to make it better than the experts having worked on it. The simplest and fastest general purpose implementation is probably the `ArrayDeque` and there's hardly anything to improve.

What you're doing is strange at best:

- Instead of appending an element, you copy the whole content. Why?
- You insert the new element at the highest index, why? This way your poll (dequeue, remove, whatever)  must remove the index at element 0, which is slow for `ArrayList`.

Actually, I have no idea how your `poll` may look like. In any case, your enqueue doesn't do what I'd expect from a method called like this.

Comment: I am not implementing a whole queue, the whole purpose of the assignment is to make this one code faster. Please check the update.

Comment: @MandM: To me it all looks like a big nonsense. The `enqueue` method returns a new `MyQueue` rather than modifying the old one. The latter would be obviously much faster, but it's a completely different thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use a LinkedList instead of an ArrayList. You don't need indexed access in a queue, but you do need fast enqueue/dequeue. If you need indexed access. It isn't really a queue at all. And just use the add() method, don't create a whole new queue every time. Your enqueue() method should return 'this', or void. And don't allow the caller to supply the list: create your own.

Comment: basically, as I mentioned, my enqueue should return a new queue (or list) to the caller, that has the original array of theirs with the  new element appended to it, WITHOUT changing the old one. Hence I have to make a copy. but I know this way i slow, hence the whole purpose of asking

Comment: @MandM Review that requirement. It is absurd.

Comment: I would, but theres not much we can do, the whole assignment is revolving around this. do you think using LinkedList would be an efficient boost? i tried to check the time with System.nanotime. They both had more or less the same execution time..